# What is this Bash (and/or other shell?) construct called?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, stdout

What is the construct in bash called where you can take wrap a command that outputs to stdout, such that the output itself is treated like a stream?  In case I'm not describing that so well, maybe an example will do best, and this is what I typically use it for: applying diff to output that does *not* come from a file, but from other commands, where

```
cmd
```

is wrapped as

```
<(cmd)
```

By wrapping a command in such a manner, in the example below I determine that there a difference of one between the two commands that I am running, and then I am able to determine that one precise difference.  What is the construct/technique of wrapping a command as <(cmd) called?  Thanks

```
[builder@george v6.5 html]$ git status | egrep modified | awk '{print $3}' | wc -l
51
[builder@george v6.5 html]$ git status | egrep modified | awk '{print $3}' | xargs grep -l 'Ext\.define' | wc -l
50
[builder@george v6.5 html]$ diff <(git status | egrep modified | awk '{print $3}') <(git status | egrep modified | awk '{print $3}' | xargs grep -l 'Ext\.define')
39d38
< javascript/reports/report_initiator.js
```

ADDENDUM
The revised command using the advice for using git's ls-file should be as follows (untested):

```
diff <(git ls-files -m) <(git ls-files -m | xargs grep -l 'Ext\.define')
```

Comment: Don't parse `git status`, use `git ls-files -m`!

Comment: It is called an abomination.  ;)

Comment: Nonsense, especially when using 'git ls-files -m', which shortens the command immensely.  Do you have another, better way of determining which one of the 51 files did not contain 'Ext\.define'?

Comment: @George: yes.  Use a standard pipe, or use an interpolating heredoc, or put the input in the filesystem.  process substitution is a fairly good idea, but for backwards compatibility reasons with historical shells, it should be avoided.  It's non-portability makes it (IMO) an "abomination".

Comment: @william I don't agree with that at all. Why in the world would anyone care if some command line works with some ancient version of bash?  There are a very select group of people, like sysadmins of many varied machines, some old, that should care.

Comment: @George it's not a matter of things working in an ancient version of bash--there are shells other than bash.  Anyone writing sh should be aware of issues like this, because thousands of hours have been wasted tracking down bugs or re-writing scripts that used non-portable constructs.  If you are using it in an interactive script, go for it.  If you are using process-substitution in a script, make sure you specify /bin/bash and not /bin/sh, and consider yourself lucky if you never have to spend time maintaining someone else's non-portable script!

Comment: This is a tempest in a teapot.  My example code was clearly executed from the command line.  I say we all go back to using pencil and paper for everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Answer (score 6):

This is called [`Process Substitution`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)

Comment: I'm accepting the other answer despite yours being identical because that user also gave me a useful git tip, hope you understand, I was wondering how I was going to choose between two identical simultaneous answers

Comment: Well, not quite simultaneous, I'd beaten Mat by about 30 seconds, but only because he was helping you with your problem, not with your question. Guess that's fair.

Comment: Yes I see now finally I have a screen that says you answered 14 mins ago, and Mat 13 mins ago

Comment: @GeorgeJempty: feel free to change your accept, I won't be offended at all :)

Comment: I'm sticking with it Mat, you also gave me the git tip; if I could accept both I would.  Thanks both for the answer, I use this fairly frequently, and sometimes get asked *what* are you doing, and it's embarassing to answer "I don't know, but it just works" ;)

Comment: @Mat: Rather think you deserve it, frequently assisting people on SO is helping them with their actual problem rather than answering their [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). :)

Answer (score 1):

This is process substitution, as you have been told.  I'd just like to point out that this also works in the other direction.  Process substitution with >(cmd) allows you to take a command that writes to a file and instead have that output redirected to another command's stdin.  It's very useful for inserting something into a pipeline that takes an output filename as an argument.  You don't see it as much because pretty much every standard command will write to stdout already, but I have used it often with custom stuff. Here is a contrived example:

```
$ echo "hello world" | tee >(wc)
hello world
      1       2      12
```